# Load 64-bit address of a symbol to a register on AArch64

Tags: assembly, arm, constants, arm64

I am linking an AArch64 assembly file to a project in C/C++. The C/C++ code contains a variable in which a function pointer is stored. I need to call this function (if the pointer is not null), so my plan is to load the address of the variable in `X1`, then load the value of the variable into `X2` by means of `LDR X2, [X1]`, then call the function by means of `BLR X2`. However, I can't figure out: how to load in `X1` the address of the variable?

A code example follows. In it I need to load to `X1` the 64-bit address of variable `_funcPtr`.

```
    .syntax unified
    .text
    .global _funcPtr
    .p2align 2
    .global _myAsmFunc
    .type _myAsmFunc, %function
_myAsmFunc:
    @ Load the address of _funcPtr to X1 here
```

I am using GNU / Clang assembler.

Comment: `ldr x1, =_funcPtr` as usual?

Comment: @Jester, do you mean a macro/pseudo-instruction which the assembler should expand into real instructions?

Comment: Yes and no :) This is indeed a pseudo instruction but it expands to a real `ldr` and a literal pool entry.

Comment: Actually, it probably translates into a couple of math instruction instead under later CPUs which have added instructions just for such an emergency.

Comment: @Jester, thanks, but I'll be able to check whether this works much later. You may want to post this as an answer now.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan No, it will generate a PC relative LDR instruction to load a 64-bit value in the literal pool. If you want to load a 64-bit address into a register without using a load instruction you need to use the MOVL pseudo-instruction. However it requires 4 instructions (1 MOVZ and 3 MOVLs), so it's 4 bytes longer in total size and probably significantly slower.

Comment: I was thinking of ADRP xX, #label : ADD xY, xX, #imm.  This of course is a PC relative load instruction as you say and is further optimized on newer CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
adrp    x1,:got:_funcPtr
ldr     x1,[x1,:got_lo12:_funcPtr]
```

loading *_funcPtr*'s address from the global offset table. *_funcPtr* has to be defined as *extern*, otherwise there will be no entry in the GOT for your function.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't figure out: how to load in X1 the address of the variable?

==>  I think you can do it by

```
ldr x1, =var1
```

Then the compiler allocates a space for storing the 'address of var1' in an address (let's call this is from current PC + 0x100, for example 0x40000100), and above code is translated actually to

```
   addr            instr.      disassem.
0x40000000    58000801        ldr x1, 0x100   <== here 0x100 is PC-relative
...
0x40000100    50003400        .inst. undefined   <== 0x50003400 is actual address of var1, it's just a data
```

As you would know, this is because single ldr instruction can't contain 32bit immediate data in itself. (so use PC-relative address which is 19bit.)

Answer (score 1):

Using PC-relative addressing, you can actually load the pointer *value* itself from static storage in 2 instructions, or just its address with 2 pure ALU instructions (which some CPUs may fuse and handle as a single wide instruction).  No need to go through the GOT unless you actually need to support symbol-interposition.

As usual, ask a compiler to make an asm example for you:

```
void (*fptr)(void);

auto load_global() {
    return fptr;
}
```

g++ 8.2 -O3 for AArch64, [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:23,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:23,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:6,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:6,startLineNumber:7),source:%27void+(*fptr)(void)%3B%0A%0Aauto+load_global()+%7B%0A++++return+fptr%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aauto+address_of_global()+%7B%0A++++return+%26fptr%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:51.62664728751369,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g820,filters:(b:%271%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%271%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-fPIE%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27ARM64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.373352712486316,l:%274%27,m:61.238761238761235,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+ARM64+gcc+8.2%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:38.76123876123875,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:48.373352712486316,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).  You may be able to use `fptr` directly instead of the `.LANCHOR0` alias for it, although the 2nd symbol at the same location may avoid linker complaints about not going through the GOT for a symbol with global (instead of hidden) ELF visibility.

```
.text
load_global:
        adrp    x0, .LANCHOR0
        ldr     x0, [x0, #:lo12:.LANCHOR0]
        ret

# and later, in .bss where fptr is declared.
 .bss
 .align  3
 .set    .LANCHOR0,. + 0     # .LANCHOR0 has the same address as fptr, but isn't .global
                             # could be .LANCHOR0: instead of .set
.global fptr
fptr:
   .zero   8
```

I trimmed the asm output (`.size` and `.type`), and reordered the directives into a more sensible order to group related things.

---

**To actually just get the address:**

```
auto address_of_global() {
    return &fptr;
}
```

```
address_of_global:
        adrp    x0, .LANCHOR0
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:.LANCHOR0
        ret
```

Again, this probably works with `fptr` directly instead of `.LANCHOR0`.  And definitely if `fptr` is `static` (file-private), not `.global`.

---

Note that this is no different from loading a `uintptr_t x;` global variable; what you do with the var's value once you have it in a register is entirely up to you.  Checking it for non-zero and calling through it doesn't change how you load it.  I used a C++ function pointer just to follow the question, even though it makes the syntax harder, especially if you use C where `auto` doesn't work the same way as C++11.

This **assumes that `fptr` is within [ADRP range](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/a/A64-General-Instructions/ADRP) (+-4GiB) of your code**, not an arbitrary 64-bit distance away.  This is what compilers assume for global variables normally, so this memory model is fully standard.  The linker defaults put the `.rodata`, `.bss` and `.data` section near enough to `.text` for this to be fine, unless you have some huge arrays in static storage.

(Then you might need to use a "medium" code model where huge objects go in a special section that might be too far away from code for ADRP to work, where addresses would be handled less efficiently, e.g. via the GOT or a nearby literal pool, like other answers show.)